# uint8_t, uint16_t and uint32_t not recognized in PCLint

Tags: pc-lint

When running PCLint on code base it seems that the data types uint8_t, uint16_t and uint32_t are not recognized. 
For example:

```
uint8_t variable1 = 0;
```

The following errors are received from Lint:

```
129: declaration expected, indentifier 'uint8_t' ingnored
129: declaration expected, indentifier 'variable1' ingnored
10: Expecting identifier or other declarator
19: Useless declaration
```

Anything that uses 'variable1' the following errors are displayed:

```
40: Undeclared identifier 'variable1'
63: Expected an lvalue
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you include the compiler specific .lnt file on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons why PC-Lint fails to recognize `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`:

1. `#include <stdint.h>` is missing in your source code file

PC-Lint parses your code like the "dumbest" compiler. In order to know about the fixed-width integer types defined by C99 it requires an include of the appropriate header file. This can be either `<stdint.h>` or `<inttypes.h>`. Some compilers might know about the fixed-width integer types even without an include of these header files.

2. The header `<stdint.h>` cannot be found by PC-Lint

PC-Lint evaluates your code independently of your specific compiler. It does not bring along its own set of standard headers though. Therefore it needs to know where it will find system headers like `<stdint.h>` in your file system (usually the compiler installation path). This is usually done by providing a compiler-specific configuration file (e.g. `co-gcc.lnt`) at the command line. Gimpel Software (authors of PC-Lint) provide a large set of these files at their website: https://gimpel.com/html/ptch90.htm